# Conditionally make shared_ptr in initializer list null

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, shared-ptr

I am in a situation where I need to make a `shared_ptr` either `null` or contain an instance of class `Bar`.

The approach below does not work though since, `Bar` and `nullptr` are not of the same type. How can achieve this?

```
 class Bar {};

 class Foo {

    private:
       shared_ptr<Bar> b;

    public:
       Foo() : b(true ? Bar() : nullptr) {
       }

 };
```

Comment: For this pattern in general (i.e. computing an initializer), you can use a private helper function that does whatever it takes to generate the initial value. Between inlining, move semantics, and RVO, the overhead of this approach can be driven nearly to zero.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have 2 distinct Foo constructors, one of which takes parameters for bar, and the other creates a nullptr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b(true ? std::make_shared<Bar>() : nullptr)`

Comment: nice! how does this work though? nullptr is of type nullptr_t and std::make_shared<Bar>() returns a shared_ptr<Bar> type

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Foo() : b(true ? std::make_shared<Bar>() : nullptr) {}
```

My suggestion will be to push that logic to a helper function.

```
class Foo {

   private:
      std::shared_ptr<Bar> b;

      static std::shared_ptr<Bar> getB(bool flag)
      {
         return (flag ? std::make_shared<Bar>() : nullptr);
      }

   public:
      Foo() : b(getB(true)) {}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your initialization of `b` is incorrect.

```
b(Bar())
```

won't compile either.  You'd need

```
b(new Bar())
```

and the equivalent with the ternary operator:

```
b(true?new Bar():nullptr)
```

is fine.  However, I would recommend avoiding naked `new` wherever possible, and use

```
b(true?maked_shared<Bar>():nullptr)
```

Although `make_shared` returns a different type to `nullptr`, they can be coerced into the same type by constructing an empty `shared_ptr` from the `nullptr`